# EmbeJS: How to force action inside {{input..}} react earlier then action in its parent?

Tags: ember.js

I have a

```
<div ... {{action "divAction"}}>
   ...
   {{input type="checkbox" change=(action "checkboxAction")}} 

   ...
</div>
```

the problem is that `divAction` fires before `checkboxAction`. How to force `checkboxAction` first?

I also tried:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=checked}}
```

and in code

```
checked: true,

checkedChanged: function() {
   .....
   return false;
}.observes('checked'),
```

The result is the same.

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2ce9f8b7d565c742a20654be1748d8b9?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2C). See output in console when you tick on checkboxes. They don't work. If you remove action on the  then everything works fine. I need to make it work with action but checkboxes fire FIRST.

**SOLVED:**
Wrapping `{{input}}` inside `stopPropagation` made a job (updated [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2ce9f8b7d565c742a20654be1748d8b9?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2C)):

```
  <span onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
    {{input type="checkbox"  checked=checked }}
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=checked change=(action "checkedChangedAction") }}
  </span>
```

Comment: what version of ember-source is this?

Answer (score 1):

> How to force checkboxAction first?

You can't -- getting explicit order requires managing the function invocation more explicitly.

if you pass `divAction` as a value / argument, then `checkboxAction` could call `divAction` at the bottom of the function.

Like:

```js
checkboxAction = () => {
  /* ... */

  this.args.divAction();
}
```